# I am using yajra datatables package laravel 5.1. I have sent some from controller to view page, Now i want to search with two fields. How to do that?

Tags: laravel, search

My controller code is:

```
 $bussearches = Bussearch::where('id', 'like', '%');
```

sending $bussearches to the view page. Now I want to input two fields and search the two data into $bussearches array in view page. Please help me...
my view page is:

```
<div class="col-md-12">    
<div class="form-group required col-md-6" id="form-departure-error">
    {!! Form::label("departure","departure place",["class"=>"control-label col-md-3"]) !!}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {!! Form::text("departure",null,["class"=>"form-control required","id"=>"departure"]) !!}
        <span id="departure-error" class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group required col-md-6" id="form-arrival-error">
    {!! Form::label("arrival","arrival place",["class"=>"control-label col-md-3"]) !!}
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {!! Form::text("arrival",null,["class"=>"form-control required","id"=>"arrival"]) !!}
            <span id="arrival-error" class="help-block"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
        <a href="javascript:ajaxLoad('bussearch/searchlist')" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i>Back</a>
        {!! Form::button("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk'></i> Save",["type" => "submit","class"=>"btn btn-primary"])!!}
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to input **departure** and **arrival** values as variable from the input fields and search the two values within the array **'$bussearches'** and show the expected data as table view.

`

Comment: Please improve your question. Post the method that you used, html code with fields etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use several where methods to achieve this. For example:

```
$bussearches = Bussearch::where('id', 'like', '%' . $field1 . '%')
     ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $field2 . '%')
     ->paginate(10);
```

You can use `where` or `orWhere` that means you're searching with conditions `AND` or `OR` sql-query

Comment: in view page 'view.blade.php', how do i use sql query? firstly i need to input two fields, secondly taking it to variables using ajax, and finally i have to the inputing variables with controller sent data '$bussearches'.